# Почему mobx выдает ошибку Reaction[observerobserved]?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, mobx

Всем привет,прошу помощи!
Получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую mobx+mobx-state-tree + react + socket.io
Впервые пишу чат.
Суть первой ошибки мне вообще не ясна,нигде описания не нарыл..
А вот вторая ошибка очень странная для меня, map не может найти данные внутри массива если передавать их атрибутам или в html элементы,но если внутри этого же цикла использовать console.log() и в него прокидывать данные,в консоли все прекрасно отображается..

Шаги по получению ошибки:
1.Я запрашиваю через api по сокетам список чатов
2.внутрь socket.on('chatlist',(data)=>{
//пробрасываю mobx-state-tree экшн который кладет данные в стор mobx-state-tree
acition(data)

})
Это все внутри другой функции
3. дальше я достаю из MST стора данные и пробрасываю props компоненту который мапит  чат лист
4.После того как данные прилетели ловлю ошибку на первой итерации что свойство 'user' не найдено,но там же в консоль лог все отображает норм

Вот код моего mobx-state-tree модели для чата

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код компонента который рендерит этот массив

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки решены:
Reaction[observerobserved] возникает когда компонент не является наблюдаемым,решение:
Обернуть компонент в observe()

По массиву проблема была в том что в мапе я обращался к несуществующему элементу,так как я брал индекс первого элемента,а во втором элементов может быть всего два,и дойдя до 2 индекса,обращение во втором массиве в котором нет этого индекса,выдавало undefined..